# How do I reference the GameObject that my script is attached to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

sorry it has been years since I've used C# and I know this is a simple question.  But How do I reference the GameObject that my script is attached to?  Here is specifically what I am trying to do:

```
if (Component.gameObject.position.y < -29)
        {
            Component.gameObject.position.y = 2;
            Component.gameObject.position.x = 0;
            Component.gameObject.position.z = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Via the property [`Component.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) .. please checkout the API before questions of this type ;)

Comment: @derHugo I tried that but as you can see it did not work.  Could you answer with this new context perhaps?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via the property [`Component.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html)

You wouldn't access it like a `static` field via the `Component` class!

Your class already **is** a `Component` and has access to its own fields. Please see the provided API example!

It is simply

```
this.gameObject
```

where `this` can be omitted in most cases.

---

Anyway a [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) has no `position` .. only the [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) component attached to it.

Luckily `Component` also has the shortcut property [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) already which basically equals `gameObject.transform` so what you want is

```
if(transform.position.y < 29)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(0,2,0);
}
```